# Paypal mobile SDK : Authorize a token returned from SetExpressCheckout method

Tags: android, ios, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm implementing a REST api (which will be used by both web and mobile clients) for making paypal recurring payments, and found out that this can be done with paypal express checkout process.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/

Is there a method in android and ios paypal sdk to Authorize a token returned from 'SetExpressCheckout' method, and send the PAYERID back to the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not.  The PayPal payment portion of the mSDK in both iOS and Android run the complete PayPal payment.  If you simply wanted a mobile version of EC then you can look at MEC [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mobile-express-checkout/).  However keep in mind that MEC is not a native solution.